# URL redirect to include slash in web.config is not working

Tags: url, redirect, iis, http-redirect

I currently have the following web.config set up to rewrite the url but a client would like to have a back slash added to the end of each url for SEO purposes. Is there a better way to write the below to incorporate the slash or is there a rule that could be added to add the slash once the url has been rewritten? I've tried the suggestions here but it didnt work:

https://www.rewriteguide.com/iis-add-remove-trailing-slash/

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="submit.cfm" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?topNav={R:1}" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="submit.cfm" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?topNav={R:1}&amp;subNav={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL3" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="submit.cfm" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?topNav={R:1}&amp;subNav={R:2}&amp;subsubNav={R:3}" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL4" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="submit.cfm" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?topNav={R:1}&amp;subNav={R:2}&amp;subsubNav={R:3}&amp;subsubsubNav={R:4}" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL5" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="submit.cfm" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?topNav={R:1}&amp;subNav={R:2}&amp;subsubNav={R:3}&amp;subsubsubNav={R:4}&amp;subsubsubsubNav={R:5}" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: None of your rules adds the slash to the end of URLs, so do you want someone else to write that for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```xml
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Source: [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules - https, www, and more](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/#add-trailing-slash)

Comment: so i've worked out that your code (thanks for that) needs to go before all the other rules so that works now. However ,it doesn't seem to add it to the main domain, so if I click on the home button it goes to https://thesite.com but ideally I would like it to go to https://thesite.com/

Comment: I think it works for the root domain too. The browser hides any / at the end of a root domain.

Comment: If it doesn't catch the root domain with the current two conditions, then you'd simply add a third condition matching on the URL field or similar.